# I am trying to display a dropdownlist in the grid?

Tags: html, css

**I am trying to display a dropdownlist in the grid but the dropdown does not appear when it is clicked. Instead of seeing the "text" of the dropdown that corresponds to the numeric "value" (an enumeration) I am only seeing a "textbox" where the dropdownlist should appear. Another odd behavior happens when I randomly click on the grid the dropdown will appear intermittently.**

Comment: A minimum not-working code sample would be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Will Work for you
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid()
          .Name("Grid")
          .Columns(
              column =>
              {
                  column.Bound(e => e.LanguageName).Title("Language Name");
                  column.Bound(e => e.CountryName).Title("Language Name");
                  column.Bound(e => e.CountryID).ClientTemplate(

```
                  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Country,"text","value"), "---  Select ---", new { @class = "form-control dropdownErp" }).ToString()).Title("Country Name"); 


           }
      )
              .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))



    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .ServerOperation(true)
  .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.ID);

    })
                    .Read(read => read.Action("Getdata", "Language").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))



                      )
    )
```